# DB2 nested correlated table reference in sub-sub-query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a database that contains audit tables.  These audit tables contain copies of records from the main tables, copied in from triggers, and I need to create a sort of point-in-time report from these audit records.

The tables each have an `updated_at` column which is the timestamp of when the record was inserted - mix this with an id column or something and we can pinpoint a specific record (I mention this because the id columns cannot be unique in these tables).

What I need to do is pull records with some column filters, then get only the "most recent" version of those records (so, typically a `MAX(updated_at)` type return set).  Then, I need to join 3 other audit tables and grab the related records from those - but the "most recent" records as well (the last table, `audit_products` I use to grab a `COUNT()` of the number of products associated to the related record)... but only up to the `updated_at` that gets returned from the initial part of the query - therein lies my problem.

This is the query (that doesn't work) that I would like to run... theoretically:

```
SELECT gr.id, gr.title_e, gr.title_f, wp.updated_at, wp.to_epmd_orig, wp.to_epmd_revise, wp.to_epmd_actual, lc.code_e, lc.code_f, pr.total
  FROM (
     SELECT fw.id, fw.group_id, fw.updated_at, fw.to_epmd_orig, fw.to_epmd_revise, fw.to_epmd_actual, fw.to_epmd_late_code
       FROM audit_pc_pub_workplans AS fw
      RIGHT JOIN (
         SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
           FROM audit_pc_pub_workplans
          WHERE completed = 1 AND DATE(to_epmd_actual) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2014-03-31'
          GROUP BY id
      ) AS aw ON (aw.id = fw.id AND aw.updated_at = fw.updated_at)
  ) as wp
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT fg.id, fg.updated_at, fg.title_e, fg.title_f
       FROM audit_groups AS fg
      RIGHT JOIN (
         SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
           FROM audit_groups
          WHERE updated_at <= wp.updated_at AND del_date IS NULL
          GROUP BY id
      ) AS ag ON (ag.id = fg.id AND ag.updated_at = fg.updated_at)
  ) AS gr ON (gr.id = wp.group_id)
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT fc.id, fc.code_e, fc.code_f
       FROM audit_wp_late_codes AS fc
      RIGHT JOIN (
         SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
           FROM audit_wp_late_codes
          WHERE updated_at <= wp.updated_at AND delete_date IS NULL
          GROUP BY id
      ) AS ac ON (ac.id = fc.id AND ac.updated_at = fc.updated_at)
  ) AS lc ON (lc.id = wp.to_epmd_late_code)
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT fp.prod_group, COUNT(DISTINCT fp.id) AS total
       FROM audit_products AS fp
      RIGHT JOIN (
         SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
           FROM audit_products
          WHERE updated_at <= wp.updated_at AND del_date_2 IS NULL
          GROUP BY id
      ) AS ap ON (ap.id = fp.id AND ap.updated_at = fp.updated_at)
      GROUP BY fp.prod_group
  ) AS pr ON (pr.prod_group = gr.id)
ORDER BY gr.title_e ASC
;
```

For the sake of completeness, I've left all column names in there as-is, but as outsiders you can ignore some of them obviously.  The key ones are really the `id` type columns which are used in the `ON ()` statements mostly, and the `updated_at` columns that all the tables have.

The problem is specifically my reference to `wp.updated_at` in all of the sub-sub queries in the `LEFT JOIN`s.  I read up and found that I can use a key word `LATERAL` when doing a join which is supposed to allow me to expose the `wp` table, and it does in fact let me run the query... but when I run that query (by the way, audit_products table has about 8M records), I give up after 2hrs of waiting.

Is there any way that this query can be rewritten to work within a reasonable amount of time?  I'd even accept 15-30 minutes to run... just not hours.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, the use of `DATE(to_epmd_actual)` is causing it to ignore (relevant portions of) indices on that column.  Use `to_epmd_actual >= '2013-04-01' AND to_epmd_actual < '2014-04-01'` (see [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for why).  It'd be good to get some sample data/desired results, but this should be simplifiable, yeah - that'll help knowing what's required and what can be removed (I'm a bit suspicious of the use of `RIGHT JOIN`s in this situation).

Comment: Yes, the use of `DATE()` cast the field so that i could specify just a date without a time.  The delay in doing that is minimal so I'm not worried about that.  The `RIGHT JOIN` was intentional, though really should be an `INNER JOIN`... again though, i don't believe they are causing the real slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think you need outer joins in your query. Secondly, consider using the OLAP function ROW_NUMBER() to retrieve the latest records -- it usually works faster than aggregation. Something like:

```
SELECT gr.id, gr.title_e, ...
  FROM (
     SELECT fw.id, ... fw.to_epmd_late_code, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn
       FROM audit_pc_pub_workplans 
       WHERE completed = 1 AND DATE(to_epmd_actual) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2014-03-31'
  ) as wp
  INNER JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT fg.id, fg.updated_at, fg.title_e, fg.title_f,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
       FROM audit_groups
       WHERE updated_at <= wp.updated_at and wp.rn = 1 AND del_date IS NULL
  ) AS gr ON (gr.id = wp.group_id)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that syntax example.  I have something working with all but the `audit_products` table, as i need to do an aggregate count on that and i can't figure out a way to do so without involving a sub-sub query.  As soon as that happens, the query takes forever to run.